# NavigatorIOS not rendering initialroute

Tags: react-native

I pretty much copied and pasted the demo code from Facebook, but the initialRoute component does not render. Answers like setting flex:1 as suggested by similar questions didn't work for me. Any tips?

[image: doesn't work]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
  StatusBar,
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
import NativeThing from './components/ReactNative';

export default class ListsList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: MyScene,
          title: 'My Initial Scene',
        }}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyScene extends Component {

  _onForward = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Current Scene: { this.props.title }</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onForward}>
          <Text>Tap me to load the next scene</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ListsList', () => ListsList);
```

Comment: I know you said you added `flex:1` but in that code snippet you are never actually applying the `container` style to any view. Have you tried to do so?

Comment: Yeah this is the code copy and pasted from the react-native documentation. I've played around with adding `flex: 1` to almost every component with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation bar by default overlaps the content of MyScene component. This is the default behaviour of the NavigatorIOS with a translucent 
navigation bar.

So you have two options:

1. Add style `paddingTop: 64` to the View of MyScene.
2. Add property `translucent={ false }` to the NavigatorIOS